# DuplicateWidgetID when trying to capture frame from videostream

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, streamlit

I was trying to learn CV & streamlit with a simple photo booth which saves and image when button is pressed.
I'm not sure why but I'm not able to get stream on the webpage.
Here's the code:

```
import streamlit as st
import cv2
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

def take_photo():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    if not cap.isOpened():
        st.error("Unable to access the camera")
        return

    st.write("Press the button to take a photo!")
    frame_placeholder = st.empty()

    streaming = True
    while streaming:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
            frame_placeholder.image(frame, channels="BGR")
        else:
            st.error("Failed to capture the photo")
            break

        if st.button("Take Photo"):
            streaming = False
            # Save the image with the current timestamp
            current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
            file_path = f"photo_{current_time}.png"
            cv2.imwrite(file_path, frame)
            st.success(f"Photo saved as {file_path}")

    cap.release()

def main():
    st.title("Simple Photo Booth App")
    take_photo()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Tried to add a key value for the button as suggested by streamlit but that didn't help either.

Comment: Haven't you update streamlit? Released: Nov 2, 2023

Comment: @toyotaSupra, I'm using the latest package 1.28.1 on windows with python 3.8.18